# Alterar texto ao entrar no host da amazon c2

Tags: linux, amazon-aws, centos

Eu procurei no site da amazon e não achei como alterar o texto que mostra ao entrar, é esse da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o local que altera esse texto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acessa os arquivos:

```
/etc/issue
/etc/motd
```

Alteres eles (principalmente o motd) com o `nano` ou `vim`.

Um site que gera:

http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=testall&h=3&v=3&c=c&f=Crawford2&t=CAROL

Comment: Cool +1 (ou mesmo `figlet Carol` :) )

Comment: Figlet precisa instalar caso não tenha. `apt install figlet`

Comment: obrigado @DiegoSouza funcionou